# Does $y(y+1) \leq (x+1)^2$ imply $y(y-1) \leq x^2$?

Tags: inequality

Can anyone see how to prove the following?

If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers with $y\geq 0$ and $y(y+1) \leq (x+1)^2$ then $y(y-1) \leq x^2$.

It seems it is true at least according to Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given $y^2 + y \le x^2 + 2x + 1$,  if possible, let $x^2 < y(y-1)$.  Clearly $y > 1$.

Then $x^2 + (2x + 1) < y^2 - y + (2x + 1)$
So $y^2 + y < y^2 - y + 2x + 1$, which resolves to $y < x + \frac{1}{2}$.

Hence we also have $y - 1 < x - \frac{1}{2}$.
As $y > 1$, the LHS is positive, and we can multiply the last two to get
$y(y-1) < x^2 - \frac{1}{4} \implies y(y-1) < x^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks. Found your direct approach quite neat (+1), especially after the condensing.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? You had $y<x+1/2$, and in the last step you multiplied $y-1$ by $y$ and $x-1/2$ by $x+1/2$. However, this inequality is not in the same proportion anymore, because $y$ does not equal $x+1/2$. It's like if I try to prove that $a<b$, and to solve this I say $a<b+5$. While this is true, this changes the inequality.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Oh, somehow I missed that. Sorry. I'll delete my errors, to keep the comments clear. I was wrong.

Comment: @Ovi  I seem to have missed some of the dialogue, however hope your concern has been resolved.  Here we are not worried about preserving proportion, only about preserving order.  In your example, $a < b \implies a < b+5$, though $a:b \neq a:(b+5)$ in general.

Comment: I followed the proof, but I don't understand how to justify multiplying the equations (or how to think of doing that in the first place). I would appreciate any clarification!

Comment: @user121955 To show contradiction, we need to find a good upper bound for $y(y-1)$. Hence the motive to multiply. Multiplication is justified as both LHS and RHS are non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's true.

First note that if $0 \le y \le 1$, then $y - 1 \le 0$, so $y(y-1) \le 0 \le x^2$, and the inequality is true.

So we can assume $y > 1$. Then, as $y(y+1) = (y + \frac12)^2 - \frac14$ (by [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)), the given $y(y+1) \le (x+1)^2$ becomes $(y + \frac12)^2 - \frac14 \le (x+1)^2$, and in particular $(y + \frac12)^2 \le (x+1)^2$ so $y \le x+\frac12$.

Then $y(y-1) = (y-\frac12)^2 - \frac14 \le x^2 - \frac14$, which is a stronger inequality than what you wanted.

If you're interested in how to arrive at this, the [first version of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/363232/1) does this whole thing in a more straightforward (but longer) way; this is cleaner.