# $1^3 + \dotsb + n^3 = (1 + \dotsb + n)^2$: reason?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

We have 
$$
1^3 + \dotsb + n^3 = (1 + \dotsb + n)^2
$$
as we can establish by induction. But why does this hold? Can we connect it to something else?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728223/simple-beautiful-math-proof/728239#728239).

Comment: @YourAdHere Is there a higher dimensional generalization of this identity ?

Comment: @Amr In case you mean for a higher exponent than $3$, I don't think so, there is a [general formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) to sum the first $k$th powers and it doesn't take such a simple form for higher $k$.

Comment: @YourAdHere Yes I meant higher exponents. I said "dimensional" because your proof considers squares and I was asking if there is a similar argument that considers cubes for example ...

Comment: Related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61482)

Answer (score 6):

Meanwhile, it generalizes to Liouville's
$$  \sum_{k | n} \left( d(k) \right)^3 = \left( \sum_{k | n} d(k)  \right)^2  $$

Here $d(k)$ is the number of divisors of a positive integer, with $d(1)=1.$ For a prime $p,$ we get
$$ d(p^w) = w+1.  $$

The identity works because it works for a prime power, that is what the original summation formula shows. Next, both sides are number theoretic "multiplicative." A multiplicative function $f(n)$ is one that applies to integers, and which has this condition: whenever $\gcd(a,b) = 1,$ we have $f(ab) = f(a) f(b).$ Any multiplicative function is completely determined by its values on prime powers. Oh, if $f(n)$ is a multiplicative function, then 
$$ g(n) = \sum_{k|n} f(k)   $$
is also multiplicative. That requires a little proof, double sum sort of thing.

Comment: Fantastic! I had never seen this identity of Liouville.

Answer (score 4):

Funnily, we also have

$$\int_0^x t^3\: dt = \left(\int_0^x t\: dt\right)^2.$$

Comment: +1 But let's see the proof!

Comment: @AaronHall The funny thing is that the integrals $\int_0^x t^n$ were first calculated using Faulhaber polynomials. It's quite possible that the identity of the OP was known before the value of the integral $\int_0^x t^3$!

Comment: The summation version goes back to antiquity, but integration is new, and I have no idea what Faulhaber polynomials are. They sound impressive. *pops corn*

Comment: @AaronHall http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a famous proof by C. Wheatstone. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number